# Is there a bug in my code for populating a QTreeView?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtreeview

I'm using PyQt 4.4.

It's best shown using some pictures. All nodes should have leafs from 0 to 99. They are being incrementally loaded using `canFetchMore()` and `fetchMore()`. But for some reason unknown for me this works only for the root node. (Picture 1)

If I collapse and expand a node it loads additional 10 values. (Picture 2 & 3)

It's also strange, that it loads 10 values, as the code loads only 5 per call to `fetchMore()`, meaning this gets called 2 times before the code stops to load more data.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

I've written a small example to demonstrate the problem, just run it with `python test.py`.
http://snipt.org/lLh

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I took a look at the Qt source (v4.5, though I don't expect much difference between v4.4 and v4.5) for QAbstractItemView and QTreeView, and I don't think they support incremental lazy loading of child nodes.

QAbstractItemView has no notion of trees, so it only calls `fetchMore()` on the top most index. It calls `fetchMore()` when:

- Geometry is updated
- The scroll bars are moved
- Rows are inserted
- The current item is changed as a result of an autoscrolling drag & drop operation

QTreeView additionally calls `fetchMore()` when:

- An item is expanded (this is essentially the only time it calls `fetchMore()` with a non-root index)
- The view's layout needs to be relaid, such as with `expandAll()` and `collapseAll()`

I think the best solution would be to subclass QTreeView to make it call `fetchMore()` in the appropriate places and with the appropriate indices.

Comment: It does support it somewhat; you need to implement `hasChildren(QModelIndex)`, so the view doesn't need to call `rowCount(QModelIndex)`.

Comment: I am having exact problem now, QTreeview doesn't support lazy population for non top level items. Is there a way to achieve this ?